# Laravel middleware with multiple roles

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, laravel-middleware

I've been running into some issues with Laravel's middleware.
Let me tell you the basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Registered users on the site will have one of four roles:

1. Student (default): can access '**index**' and '**show**' views
2. Approver: can access previous, plus '**overview**', '**update**'
3. Editor: can access previous, plus '**create**', '**edit**' and '**store**'
4. Admin: can access **everything**

fyi: 'overview' is sort of an index view, but only for approver role and higher

What would you guys suggest is the best way to go about doing this? This is what I've done so far, but it doesn't seem to work:

---

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
...
    'approver+' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Approver::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Editor::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
    'student' => \App\Http\Middleware\Student::class,
    'approver' => \App\Http\Middleware\Approver::class,
    'editor' => \App\Http\Middleware\Editor::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
];
```

---

Http\Middleware\Admin.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if (Auth::check())
   {

        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
   }

    return redirect('login');
}
```

---

The 'User' Eloquent model:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    if($this->role_id === 4)
    { 
        return true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

I've done the exact same in the Approver and Editor middleware files, and in the isApprover and isEditor functions in the User model, only edited the checked value in the if-statement to 2 and 3 respectively.

Finally, here's what I've done in my routes\web file:

```
Route::get('scholen', 'SchoolsController@index');
Route::get('admin/scholen/overzicht', 'SchoolsController@overview')->middleware('approver+');
Route::get('admin/scholen/maken', 'SchoolsController@create')->middleware('approver+');
Route::post('scholen', 'SchoolsController@store')->middleware('approver+');
Route::get('scholen/{id}', 'SchoolsController@show');
Route::get('admin/scholen/{id}/bewerken', 'SchoolsController@edit')->middleware('admin');
Route::patch('admin/scholen/{id}', 'SchoolsController@update')->middleware('admin');
Route::delete('admin/scholen/{id}', 'SchoolsController@destroy')->middleware('admin');
```

It isn't all exactly on point yet, but I got stuck since when I log in as a user with Approver rights and try to access the schools overview, it redirects me back to the home page.

In general, it just feels like I'm working much too chaotically and not right at all, could somebody give me advice on how to do it more efficiently?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should't have a separate middleware for each role. It will get very messy very fast. It would be better to have a single role checking middleware that can check against any role passed to it.

Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\Role::class,
];
```

Http\Middleware\Role.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ... $roles)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) // I included this check because you have it, but it really should be part of your 'auth' middleware, most likely added as part of a route group.
        return redirect('login');

    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user->isAdmin())
        return $next($request);

    foreach($roles as $role) {
        // Check if user has the role This check will depend on how your roles are set up
        if($user->hasRole($role))
            return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('login');
}
```

Finally in your web routes

```
Route::get('admin/scholen/overzicht', 'SchoolsController@overview')->middleware('role:editor,approver');
Route::get('admin/scholen/{id}/bewerken', 'SchoolsController@edit')->middleware('role:admin');
```

Comment: I figured I was making it much too complicated :) That seems to work fine, thank you very much!

Comment: 3 dots "..." saved my life :)

Comment: that operator has name https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array

Comment: What if I want to group admin and editor routes and have different prefix for both? If editor logs in the URL should be `editor/dashboard` and if the admin logs in the URL should be `admin/dashboard`. What can we achieve it?

Comment: @FosAvance This funny 3 dots "..." is called Constant expressions which is available => PHP 5.6.x ;) Funny huh! :p

Comment: I am using laravel 7.x and for me, it's coming in a string. Please help me

Comment: great job doing such clean middleware, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a complement to the fafich's response.

Instead of using FOREACH you use in_array in IF, like this:

```
if (! in_array($user->hasRole($role), $roles) {
 // returns if you dont have permission
}
return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete your Handle function For Every Login Session request

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (! Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
        return redirect()->route('superadmin');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 5) {
        return redirect()->route('academy');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 6) {
        return redirect()->route('scout');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 4) {
        return redirect()->route('team');
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 3) {
        return $next($request); 
    }

    if (Auth::user()->role == 2) {
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }
}
```