# I want to display job with company that related to single postjob by category in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have three table below:
I want to display all Related job post by category in Single jobpost. and I already have single job post page but in the same single job page I want to display related jobs in the left side. see my picture!

what is controller should be and in the Single job page (view) should be? please help?

[image: Single job page]

My jobController

```
 public function show($id, $company_id)
    {
        $singleJob = Job::find($id);
        $company = Company::find($company_id);
        $similarJob = Job::with('company')->where('category_id', $id)->get();
        return view('pages.single-job')->with([
            'singleJob'=> $singleJob,
            'company'=> $company,
            'similarJob' => $similarJob,
        ]);
    }
```

My relationship

```
job.php
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

Job.php
public function category(){
return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}



//category.php
 public function job(){
        return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
    }


//company.php
    public function job(){
        return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
    }
```

Job table

```
    Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->string('jobTitle');
        $table->longText('jobDescription');
```

Company Table

```
Schema::create('company_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('admin_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Category table

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Did you forget the `category_id` in the Job migration else it will not work ? and what about the foriegn keys contraints ?

Comment: Yes, It has I forget to include I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` like this :

```
public function show($id, $company_id)
{
    $singleJob = Job::find($id);
    $company = Company::find($company_id);
    $similarJobs = Job::with('company')
                       ->whereHas('category', function ($query) use($singleJob) {
                                $query->where('id', $singleJob->category->id);
                            })
                       ->get();
    return view('pages.single-job')->with([
        'singleJob'=> $singleJob,
        'company'=> $company,
        'similarJobs' => $similarJobs,
    ]);
}
```

And in the view you can use it like this :

```
@foreach ($similarJobs as $similarJob)
    // Add the job partial, componnent or just your HTML here for showing the Job
@endforeach
```

---

For the question in the comment, to find jobs that have a company that belongs to a given industry :

```
$some_industry_type_id = 1;
$jobsOfIndustryType = Job::whereHas('company', function ($query) use($some_industry_type_id) {
                                    $query->where('industry_type_id', $some_industry_type_id);
                                })
                           ->get();
```

Comment: Hello, Marabac, I have an other question. I have the same tables above and other table call industryType(id, name) which have relationship one to many with company table(id, comapnyName, ..,industry_type_id). I want to fetch all jobs that belong to each company that has it own industryType when click on industryType_id.

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Comment: Maraboc, I have other question. how can allow two auth to access one route. I have two auth "admin" and "employer" and I want this two auth can access to one route in order to update, create, job with the same permission.

   public function __construct()
    {

            $this->middleware('auth:admin');
           // $this->middleware('auth:employer');

Comment: Sorry i wasn't arround this this two days :p

Comment: Here is a [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902371/4881811) for your case :)