# How to use multiple 'can' middlewares with route groups - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to multiple 'can' Middlewares with route groups in laravel 5.4 like bellow,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:director,super'], function() {
  Route::get('/customerDetails', 'CustomerController@index');
});
```

but it only work for first middleware in the list, and also try this method and its not working with any 'can' middleware

```
Route::middleware(['can:super', 'can:director'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/customerDetails', 'CustomerController@index');
});
```

How can I use multiple 'can' middleware correctly with route groups?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple parameters to middleware with OR condition in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712282/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-middleware-with-or-condition-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: `can:director,super` doesn't make sense. if *director* and *super* are roles, you don't use `can` because it is used for policies.

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire i have tried that, but it's not working.

Comment: @Wreigh both `director` and `super` are Gates

Answer (score 1):

Try using the or "||" operator.

```
Route::middleware(['can:super' || 'can:director'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/customerDetails', 'CustomerController@index');
});
```

" | " will check every part of condition while " || " will check in sequence starting from first. If any condition in sequence is found to be true then || stops further checking. so || is more efficient in conditional statements

Comment: try with the double pipe

Comment: Its working for all others gates when I use "||". Its not checking the middleware.

Comment: try 
Route::get('/customerDetails', 'CustomerController@index')->middleware('can:super,director');

Comment: It seems like your helper function is only setup to take the first and not process the second.

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: try referring to this post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901719/laravel-middleware-with-multiple-roles

Comment: or -> https://laravel-news.com/authorization-gates scroll down to the Define policies section

Answer (score 0):

Route::name('admin.')->prefix('admin')->middleware('auth', 'admin')->group(function () {

}