# User roles and permissions. Laravel Fortify (and not only)

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-fortify

Is there any ready-made functionality in the `Fortify` package for setting user roles and permissions (regular user, admin, main admin, etc.)?
If not, what is the correct way to implement it yourself? Alternatively, create `middleware` and an `is_admin` field in the users table. And do the check:

```
if(Auth::user()->is_admin != 1){
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'id_admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin-panel', [AdminController::class, 'admin_panel'])->name('admin_panel');
});
```

It's easy if I have 2 user roles (0 is normal user, 1 is administrator). But what if I have a regular user, an admin (can edit, update, delete products, categories, etc.), and a CEO (can give and take away admin rights, edit users' data and delete users)? Is it worth creating a second `middleware` to check `is_ceo`?

And with second `middleware` route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'id_admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/admin-panel', [AdminController::class, 'admin_panel'])->name('admin_panel');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'id_ceo'], function(){
        Route::get('/ceo-panel', [AdminController::class, 'ceo_panel'])->name('ceo_panel');
    });
});
```

Is it correct way?

Comment: sounds kinda like you are talking about roles and permissions

Comment: Yes, exactly! Wrongly put it.

Comment: This is not what fortify is about. Look at Laravel documentation for `Policies` and `Authorization`. There are several packages for handling user roles, like `Bouncer`, but you could also define your own system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's great, but I don't think I need such a complex role system. I have a small test web store. I want to make 1 admin panel and 1 CEO panel. Maybe this can be done in a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Fortify has no solution for roles, so I had to write the functionality myself.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901719/laravel-middleware-with-multiple-roles) I found a solution for my case. I have 3 permission levels.

0 - regular user,

1 - administrator,

2 - CEO.

In my `User` model I wrote this:

```
public function hasRole(){
      if($this->role === 2){
        return 1&&2;
      }else if($this->role === 1){
        return 1;
      }else{
        return redirect()->back();
      }
    }
```

A `Role` middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Role
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public const Admin = '1';
     public const CEO = '2';
     public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ... $roles){
         $user = Auth::user();
         
         $role = Auth::user()->role;

         if (!in_array($user->hasRole(), $roles)) {
           return redirect()->back();
        }

        return $next($request);
     }

}
```

`App\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   ...
   'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\Role::class,
   ...
];
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:Admin,CEO'], function(){

      Route::get('/ceo-panel', [AdminController::class, 'ceo_panel'])->middleware('role:CEO')->name('ceo_panel');

      Route::get('/admin-panel', [AdminController::class, 'admin_panel'])->name('admin_panel');

  });

});
```

Hope somebody will find this useful!

Comment: I would suggest looking at the [`Spatie Permission`](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction) package if your requirements become more complicated. Provides roles and permissions functionality and also hooks into the default auth functionality of Laravel.