# Laravel 9 Roles and Permissions

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, roles, user-management

Using the *default laravel 9 user model and migration* I registered several users (names, emails and passwords). I followed [this](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-9-custom-login-and-registration-example) guide.

But what I really want is to have **one administrator user who will be able to assign dynamically roles and permissions to those users**. For this purpose I finally abandoned the previous implementation and reinstalled laravel (also cleared database from migrations). I tried with this [guide](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-9-user-roles-and-permissions-tutorialexample.html) using the Spatie package. During this implementation I needed to install node.js on my pc in order to run

`npm install && npm run dev`

commands.

The code works but sometimes fails. There is also need to have node.js console running in order to work. If I close console the code does not work. I find the second guide too complex. Is there simpler way to implement this? **I just want the administrator to assign roles to created users and grant access to one specific route**. Can I somehow do it using the initial implementation?

Thank you a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

about role check is

[Laravel middleware with multiple roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901719/laravel-middleware-with-multiple-roles)

try laragon and if you using tailwind you need to run npm run dev to load ng latest edit and try npm run watch